# Exception occurs trying to delete a Shared Content Area using FuelSDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, java, fuel-sdk

I keep getting an error while trying to delete a Content Area using the SOAP API. I use the same base code to delete Emails and DataExtensionRows, but keep getting errors when deleting Shared Content Areas. This are an example of the SOAP requests made by the code (Using FuelSDK on a grails web application):

> 2017-12-07 15:14:04.073  INFO --- [io-8443-exec-10]
>   o.a.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap    : Outbound Message
>   --------------------------- ID: 86 Address: https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx Encoding: UTF-8
>   Http-Method: POST Content-Type: text/xml Headers: {Accept=[*/*],
>   SOAPAction=["Delete"]} Payload: 
>   
>       1tJoLEmY1iSLG8tPcgtnDIli      
>       
>         
>         
>           
>           
>           99345
>
> -------------------------------------- 2017-12-07 15:14:05.000  INFO --- [io-8443-exec-10] o.a.cxf.services.PartnerAPI.Soap.Soap    : Inbound Message
>   ---------------------------- ID: 86 Response-Code: 200 Encoding: UTF-8 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8 Headers:
>   {Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], connection=[close],
>   Content-Length=[1512], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8],
>   Date=[Thu, 07 Dec 2017 18:14:03 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5],
>   X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]} Payload:
>   
>   
>       DeleteResponse
>       urn:uuid:27282097-549f-47ad-afb5-a3d9e15f5831
>       urn:uuid:452156f6-f0bf-4b23-85a8-71a010a6f049
>       http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous
>       
>         
>           2017-12-07T18:14:03Z
>           2017-12-07T18:19:03Z
>         
>             
>       
>         
>           Error
>           Exception occurred during [DeleteContent] ErrorID: 1005707564
>           0
>           2
>           
>             
>             
>             99345
>             
>           
>         
>         8c8d7ef8-c0fe-4c11-ad00-d6869306f13e
>         Error

Comment: Can you check the settings on the shared content? Is it set to global edit or ‘view and send only?’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update, the issue was solved, it was an issue with the user permissions for reading and writing Assets (Saved Contents/Documents and Images)